# Microsoft Graph Api {"code":"ErrorInvalidPropertySet","message":"Set action is invalid for property."}

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

We use

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/{messageId}/
```

to update the just created email draft in order to send it later.

During the call we get 400 error  with the next text -> **'{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidPropertySet","message":"Set action is invalid for property."}}'**

We get it only for several mailboxes.
What could be the possible reason?
Is it related to the mailbox configuration? What should we pay attention to?

Comment: If you are trying to update a message use `PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{messageid}` this way. This error mainly occurs when you try to set a read only property. Please check if the payload which you are using is having any property with readonly access. Also go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Basically we use the same script  for a lot of accounts, so the keys in payload are the same. And for some of them it works, for some not.

Comment: (1) I would try first isolate the issue which mailboxes this call is failing. (2) Then i would see which API call that i am calling, make sure that the property exists in the given outlook object (say, message) and it's not ready only property etc. (3) Outside of your code, you can use MS graph explorer or POSTMAN make the same API call against these failing mailboxes and see still you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in internetMessageHeaders field.
We used this field in our PATCH payload, but it is not presented in PATCH method at all and sometimes Microsoft Graph API returns 400, but sometimes not.(even in case of no error this field is ignored)
So if you face this issue - just check whether you send the internetMessageHeaders field in your payload or not.

I guess it could be applied to all other readonly fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update a message use

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{messageid}
```

this way. This error mainly occurs when you try to set a read only property. Please check if the payload which you are using is having any property with readonly access. Also go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hi!
Sorry, wasn't able to answer earlier...
For now, we don't face this issue anymore, it looks like there was some issue on MS side and now it is fixed(since we didn't change anything and the number of error events decreased from 160k per day to 0).